# Laravel - translate password reset email - email.blade.php

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-localization

The following code appear in the email.blade.php:

```
@lang(
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
    'into your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
        'actionURL' => $actionUrl,
    ]
)
```

How should the json-translation file look like when it contains newlines and parameters.
All other translations in my json-file work well except the one mentioned above (second last below):

```
{
    "Reset Password Notification": "Nulstil adgangskode notifikation",
    "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.": "Du modtager denne email fordi vi har modtagen en anmodning om nulstilling af adgangskoden til din konto.",
    "Reset Password": "Nulstil adgangskode",
    "This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.": "Dette link til nulstilling af adgangskode vil udløbe om :count minutter.",
    "If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.": "Hvis du ikke har anmodet om at nulstille din adgangskode, så skal du ikke foretage dig yderligere.",
    "Verify Email Address": "Verificer e-mailadresse",
    "Please click the button below to verify your email address.": "Klik venligst på knappen nedenfor for at verificere din e-mailadresse.",
    "If you did not create an account, no further action is required.": "Hvis du ikke har anmodet om at oprette en konto, så skal du ikke foretage dig yderligere.", 
    "Regards": "Med venlig hilsen", 
    "Hello!": "Hej", 
    "Whoops!": "Ups!", 
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the :actionText button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)": "Hvis du har problemer med at klikke på :actionText-knappen, så kopier følgende adresse ind i din webbrowser:[:actionURL](:actionURL)",
    "All rights reserved.": "Alle rettigheder forbeholdt."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Halløjsa :)

Your JSON string is not properly formatted. See the proper string below:

```
"If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)": "Hvis du kan ikke klikke på knappen \":actionText\", så kopier følgende adressen ind\n i din webbrowser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)",
```

If you're working with Laravel 6+, here's how my `da.json` file looks like. It's based on the original `en.json` file, where I just replaced the default English strings with their Danish equivalents:

```
{
  "A fresh verification link has been sent to your email address.": "Der er sendt et nyt bekræftelseslink til din mailadresse.",
  "All rights reserved.": "Alle rettigheder forbeholdes.",
  "Before proceeding, please check your email for a verification link.": "Før du fortsætter, skal du kontrollere din e-mail for et bekræftelseslink.",
  "click here to request another": "Klik her for at anmode om en anden",
  "Confirm Password": "Bekræft adgangskode",
  "E-Mail Address": "Mailadresse",
  "Forbidden": "Forbudt",
  "Forgot Your Password?": "Glemt din adgangskode?",
  "Go Home": "Gå Hjem",
  "Hello!": "Hej!",
  "If you did not create an account, no further action is required.": "Hvis du ikke oprettede en konto, kræves ingen yderligere handling.",
  "If you did not receive the email": "Hvis du ikke modtog e-mailen",
  "If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.": "Hvis du ikke har anmodet om at nulstille din adgangskode, så skal du ikke foretage dig yderligere.",
  "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)": "Hvis du kan ikke klikke på knappen \":actionText\", så kopier følgende adressen ind\n i din webbrowser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)",
  "Invalid signature.": "Ugyldig signatur.",
  "Login": "Log på",
  "Logout": "Log ud",
  "Name": "Navn",
  "Not Found": "Ikke fundet",
  "Oh no": "Åh nej",
  "Page Expired": "Siden udløbet",
  "Password": "Adgangskode",
  "Please click the button below to verify your email address.": "Klik på knappen nedenfor for at bekræfte din mailadresse.",
  "Please confirm your password before continuing.": "Bekræft dit adgangskode, før du fortsætter.",
  "Regards": "Med venlig hilsen",
  "Register": "Tilmeld",
  "Remember Me": "Husk mig",
  "Reset Password": "Nulstille adgangskode",
  "Reset Password Notification": "Nulstil adgangskode notifikation",
  "Send Password Reset Link": "Send link til nulstilling af adgangskode",
  "Server Error": "Server Fejl",
  "Service Unavailable": "Service ikke tilgængelig",
  "This action is unauthorized.": "Denne handling er uautoriseret.",
  "This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.": "Dette link til nulstilling af adgangskode udløber om :count minutter.",
  "Toggle navigation": "Skift navigation",
  "Too Many Attempts.": "For mange forsøg.",
  "Too Many Requests": "For mange anmodninger",
  "Unauthorized": "Uberettiget",
  "Verify Email Address": "Bekræft mailadresse",
  "Verify Your Email Address": "Bekræft din mailadresse",
  "We won't ask for your password again for a few hours.": "Vi anmoder ikke om din adgangskode igen i et par timer.",
  "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.": "Du modtager denne email fordi vi har modtaget en anmodning om nulstilling af adgangskoden til din konto.",
  "Your email address is not verified.": "Din mailadresse er ikke bekræftet.",
  "Whoops!": "Ups!"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: On Laravel 8 how to format that string??